# Flot will not Zoom with xaxis in time mode

Tags: flot, zooming, mode

My graph zoomed great until I changed the xaxis to mode: "time".  Now I can't zoom.  The graph renders and looks good, but does not zoom.  Does FLOT support zooming for time based graphs?
Thanks

$(function () {

var line1_data  = [[1309507200000,82], [1310112000000,76], [1310976000000,71], [1311235200000,76], [1311753600000,82]];
var line2_data  = [[1309507200000,60], [1310112000000,40], [1311235200000,60], [1311753600000,80], [1318233600000,60]];

var data = [line1_data, line2_data];

```
var placeholder2 = $("#placeholder2");
var options = {
    series: { lines: { show: true }, shadowSize: 0  },
    xaxis:  { mode: "time", zoomRange: [0.1, 10]    },
    yaxis:  { zoomRange: [0.1, 10]                  },
    zoom:   { interactive: true }
};

var plot = $.plot(placeholder2, data, options);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i think it might be somehow related to your zoomRange

> "zoomRange" is the interval in which zooming can happen, e.g. with
>   zoomRange: [1, 100] the zoom will never scale the axis so that the
>   difference between min and max is smaller than 1 or larger than 100.
>   You can set either of them to null to ignore.

and in your data you need pick really tiny bit of your chart to have difference less than 10

but as i said, i might be wrong i never done time based graphs